# CVRP model formulation

Tags: python, docplex

[image]

I am trying to solve CVRP problem using binary variables. `Xr,i,j` is the decision variable.
Below is the way I have created the decission variable using docplex.

```
na_travel = mymodel.binary_var_cube(vehicle, nodes, nodes, name='X');

We can take that nodes are from 0 to 10.
```

I am struggling to make below constraint,can someone give some idea how can I formulate this.

```
Constraint: The sub-tour elimination constraints (6) ensure that the solution contains no cycles disconnected from the depot
```

[image]

If any suggestion on doing this appreiciated.